# how do i loop through this associative array and save it to the database?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this request coming into server in this format , how do I save it into the database , I am new to Laravel and also I have three models , Trip(where the first 4 key value pairs are stored), Location(where the source and destination array are stored ) and then the categories are stored in a Category model

```
{
    "name": "glass cup",
    "weight" : "12kg",
    "quantity": 400,
    "source": {
         "longitude":122324,
         "latitude":231242,
         "address": "this is just a new address",
         "place_id":23234
    },
    "destinations": [
        {
             "longitude":122324,
             "latitude":231242,
             "address": "this is just a new address",
             "place_id":23234
        },
        {
            "longitude":122324,
            "latitude":231242,
            "address": "this is just a new address",
            "place_id":23234
        },
        {
            "longitude":122324,
            "latitude":231242,
            "address": "this is just a new address",
            "place_id":23234
        }
    ],
    "categories": ["food", "clothes", "utensils"]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you save it as JSON or you create the proper fileds to insert in database. Plus, dunno if you have any relationship between the tables, but to insert data you do something like:

```
$trip = new \App\Models\Trip;
$trip->name = $request->name;
$trip->weight = $request->weight;
$trip->quantity = $request->quantity;
$trip->save();
```

For destinations you just loop the items:

```
foreach ($request->destinations as $dest)
{
    $location = new \App\Models\Location;
    $location->longitude = $dest->longitude;
    $location->latitude = $dest->latitude;
    $location->address = $dest->address;
    $location->place_id = $dest->place_id;
    $location->save();
}
```

If you'd like to save the `trip id` in the `location` table, just use `$location->trip_id = $trip->id;`

Comment: i see your answer , i will try it out now

Comment: how do i attach it to a many to many relationship ? assuming i already have the intermediate table